# NPOI writes 0 bytes in the MemoryStream

Tags: c#, npoi

I need to save a report to `MemoryStream`, so I do the next:

```
byte[] result = new byte[0];

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    XlsxReport.BuildTaskReport(stream);
    result = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Below my `XlsxReport` class:

```
public sealed class XlsxReport
{
    public const string FontName = "Times New Roman";
    private const int FontSize = 14;

    private readonly IWorkbook workbook;
    // Fonts
    private readonly IFont boldFont;
    private readonly IFont defaultFont;
    // Styles
    private readonly ICellStyle cbStyle;
    private readonly ICellStyle simpleStyle;
    private readonly ICellStyle cdStyle;
    private readonly ICellStyle ldStyle;
    // Sheet
    private readonly ISheet sheet;
    private readonly int rows, columns;

    private XlsxReport(int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        // Prepare fonts
        boldFont = workbook.CreateFont();
        defaultFont = workbook.CreateFont();
        boldFont.FontHeightInPoints = FontSize;
        defaultFont.FontHeightInPoints = FontSize;
        boldFont.FontName = FontName;
        defaultFont.FontName = FontName;
        boldFont.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.Bold;
        // Prepare styles
        cbStyle = CreateCellStyle(boldFont);
        simpleStyle = CreateCellStyle(defaultFont, HorizontalAlignment.Justify);
        cdStyle = CreateCellStyle(defaultFont, HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Center, true, false);
        ldStyle = CreateCellStyle(defaultFont, HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment.Center, true, false);
        // Initialize a sheet
        sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(Headers.Page + " 1");
        CreateSheet(sheet, rows, columns, cdStyle);
    }

    private ICellStyle CreateCellStyle(IFont font, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, 
        VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, bool hasBorder = true, bool wrapText = true)
    {
        var style = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
        style.SetFont(font);
        style.Alignment = horizontalAlignment;
        style.VerticalAlignment = verticalAlignment;
        style.WrapText = wrapText;

        if (hasBorder)
        {
            SetBorder(style);
        }

        return style;
    }

    private void BuildMainHeader()
    {
        // Prepare styles
        var titleStyle = CreateCellStyle(boldFont, HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Center, false, false);
        var stampStyle = CreateCellStyle(defaultFont, HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Center, false, false);
        // Create a title
        GetCell(sheet.GetRow(0), 0, Headers.Report, titleStyle);
        // Create a timestamp
        GetCell(sheet.GetRow(2), 0, DateTime.Today.ToDateStr(), stampStyle);
        // Set regions
        var titleRegion = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, columns - 1);
        var stampRegion = new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, columns - 1);
        sheet.AddMergedRegion(titleRegion);
        sheet.AddMergedRegion(stampRegion);
    }

    private void SetBorder(ICellStyle style)
    {
        style.BorderTop = BorderStyle.Medium;
        style.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Medium;
        style.BorderLeft = BorderStyle.Medium;
        style.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Medium;
    }

    private ICell GetCell(IRow row, int index, string value, ICellStyle style)
    {
        var cell = row.GetCell(index);
        cell.SetCellValue(value);
        cell.CellStyle = style;
        cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
        return cell;
    }

    private void SetBorder(CellRangeAddress region, ISheet sheet, IWorkbook wb)
    {
        RegionUtil.SetBorderBottom(2, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.SetBorderTop(2, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.SetBorderLeft(2, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.SetBorderRight(2, region, sheet, wb);
    }

    private void CreateSheet(ISheet sheet, int rows, int columns, ICellStyle style)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            {
                var cell = row.CreateCell(j);

                if (i > 3) { cell.CellStyle = style; }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AutoSizeColumns()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
        {
            sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }

    public static void BuildTaskReport(Stream stream)
    {
        var report = new XlsxReport(5 + Count * 6, 6);
        report.BuildMainHeader();
        var sheet = report.sheet;
        // Set cell regions
        var head = report.sheet.GetRow(4);
        report.GetCell(head, 0, Headers.OrderNumber, report.cbStyle);
        report.GetCell(head, 1, Headers.TaskName, report.cbStyle);
        report.GetCell(head, 2, Headers.DateCreate, report.cbStyle);
        report.GetCell(head, 3, Headers.DateEnd, report.cbStyle);
        report.GetCell(head, 4, Headers.Priority, report.cbStyle);
        report.GetCell(head, 5, Headers.Status, report.cbStyle);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Many lines to fill rows
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Resize columns
        report.AutoSizeColumns();
        // Save changes
        report.workbook.Write(stream);
        stream.Flush();
    }
}
```

But after `using` block my `result` is still 0 bytes. I have checked in the debugger my report builder: `IWorkbook` contains a sheet and the sheet contains rows, all looks right and seems no any exceptions.
What can be a problem? It works before I have moved a code to `XlsxReport` class.

Comment: `It works before I have moved a code to XlsxReport class.` Please show us that working code as well.

Comment: @mjwills unfortunately, I can't already. We didn't notice this bug for long time.

Comment: @mjwills we are using SVN now, but we lost old data, it's a fresh repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into the same problem today. The problem was that I updated SharpZipLib library from 0.86.* to 1.0.*. And it stopped working, or at least application started to put 0 bytes into the stream. When I downgraded this library back to 0.86.* everything started to work again as it is expected.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this solution

Comment: Glad to hear that, stupid thing, accidentaly came to the solution ;)

Comment: I am having the same problem now :-( I realized that SharpZipLib version was 1.0.0. I downgraded to 0.86.0 but no success. Finally, NPOI is 2.4.0 and SharpZipLib is 0.86.0. Any other help about this?